# FileSystemMonitor to detect only once when file created in directory?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have the following code which I want to tell me whenever a new file is added to the directory the FileSystemWatcher is monitoring. The problem is, when a file is created within the directory being monitored, it raises three events- I only want one. The events raised are all "changed". Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

```
FileSystemWatcher _fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
_fileWatcher.Path = DirToMonitor;
_fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
_fileWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
_fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(_fileWatcher_Created);
_fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(_fileWatcher_Renamed);
_fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(_fileWatcher_Changed);
_fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

EDIT: I used "LastWrite" because this is being monitored at the directory-level, not the new file. The only possible changes seemed to be LastWrite, Size and Attributes. LastWrite seemed the most sensible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but I would say it is down to your NotifyFilter. Try adjusting these to included other events and that should give you what you need

For more information : [NotifyFilters enumerarion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx)

Comment: The problem is, the NotifyFilter possibilities apply to the directory being monitored- not the new file being created. So from those only LastWrite, Attributes and Size will probaby change when a new file is created.

Comment: surely by using the CreationTime filter (which should only be set when a file is created) that would be enough? Sorry, not done anything in this area before, but the example in the link implies that should be possible.

Comment: The CreationTime applies to the directory, not the new file though? When a new file is added, the directory creation time does not change? It didnt seem to work during testing- hence I ended up with LastWrite.

Comment: Taken from the link I posted "The component is set to watch for any changes in LastWrite and LastAccess time, the creation, deletion, or renaming of text files in the directory."

Comment: Changed it to CreationTime- doesnt detect the file being copied in to the  directory.

Comment: I have just copied the code from that link and ran it. It fires off the create event when files are created and copied. I suggest you base your own code from this.